# PHP page Acts as Hyper link without any code

Tags: php, html

MY php page contains 5 sections ,header,header1,section,header_nav and footer in which section and header nav acts themselfs as a link.when i click somewhere on section division or header nav division i will redirect to another page. how can i solve this ? what will be the problem ?

Comment: You have to share some code here, otherwise people can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unclosed `<a>` tag either in or before your PHP code. Close It. Problem solved question close :)